# why stack, heap's virtual address are changed at each time?

Tags: stack, emulation, 32bit-64bit, mmap, virtual-address-space

when i run program 'A', heap and stack's virtual addresses are changed although
i run the same program 'A'.

i know that stack, heap's virtual addresses are not defined in the 
executable object file(elf format). They are variable things. i can check it out by 'readelf -l' command.

but,
Why does kernal have to change the address of the stack every time although same program is runned? 
here is reason why i asked like that.

I am making a simple process emulator. 
I'm trying to emulate a progam from raspbian(32bit) in the intel cpu environment(64bit).

So, I have to design 32 bit stack. but i don't know how i emulate stack system.

I mmaped ANONYMOUS page, then i have to use it as a stack to emulate a program.
i have to imitate the way the program(32bit) use stack. But program's stack virtual address change at every single running time. I need a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be that operational system makes **address space randomization** in stack, heap to avoid security vulnerabilities.
If a attacker knows always were to find this information for processes, it could be easier to harm the system.

Comment: can you recommend me how can i decide stack base address in emulator which emulate arm-cpu 32bit program?

Comment: which emulator is this? some public available or developed by yourself?

Comment: hi! I'm a making simple emulator by myself. this program is single process emulator.

Comment: you can use some random based formula each time you calculate the initial addresses (within proper bounds). Check this paper that has examples and research about it: https://web.stanford.edu/~blp/papers/asrandom.pdf